# Unwanted margin or padding between list items

Tags: html, css

I have a small design problem in my css, and I'd like to know if someone could check it out for me.  The design problem is in the rollover effect of my horizontal navigation.  There seems to be some sort of added margin or padding, but I'm having trouble finding the problem in the css.  I will paste the code I'm using below, so you can see for yourself.  You won't be able to see the problem until you rollover the navigation list items.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="Horiznav">
  <ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link #4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link #5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Horiznav {
  background: #1F00CA;
  border-top: solid 1px #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
}
.Horiznav ul {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-Align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.Horiznav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.Horiznav ul li a {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.Horiznav ul li a:hover {
  background: #16008D;
  color: #fff;
}
#active a { border-left: 1px solid #fff; }
```

Comment: Looks pretty good ... where's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/EZSvC/

Comment: @dbaseman: The "problem" would seem to be an additional "gap" to the left of the 2nd and subsequent menu items. The gap is there all the time, it's just that it is made more obvious when you hover over the anchor, since the background-color is changed. The cause is the inline elements and white-space in the markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the `li` elements `display:inline` the problem (extra gap to the left of each menu/list item) is as a result of the white-space in the HTML markup. You can either:

### A - Get rid of the white-space in the HTML:

```
<ul><li id="active"><a href="#">Link #1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li><li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li><li><a href="#">Link #4</a></li><li><a href="#">Link #5</a></li></ul>
```

### B - Or, use the `font-size:0` trick:

Set `font-size:0` on the `ul` container and override this with `font-size:whatever` on the `li` child elements:

```
.Horiznav ul {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-Align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 0;       /* #1 */
}
.Horiznav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;    /* #2 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EZSvC/4/

### C - Or, use a floated layout:

Float the `li` elements (they are then implicitly displayed as blocks) and clear the floats on the `ul` container with `overflow:hidden`. However, you will need to give the container width and apply `margin:0 auto` if you want it centred.

http://jsfiddle.net/EZSvC/5/

Answer (score 0):

just add "display:inline-block" in "Horiznav ul li a" in you css

```
.Horiznav ul li a {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

here is the [jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSvC/3/)

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This does not seem to solve anything? In fact, this creates an additional "gap" top and bottom since the margins (padding) no longer collapse.

Comment: sorry for the comment.. then your file is looking fine in my end